# how to predict traindata using naivebayes when data is large

Tags: r, feature-selection

```
> c<-naiveBayes(f1,traindata)
```

here `f1` is used for adding the weights .

```
> pred<-predict(c,traindata)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 98.7 Mb
```

Comment: How big is the training set?  And how much memory do you have on your machine?  Have you tried garbage collecting (calling `gc()`) right before `predict`?

Comment: @mrip training data is 3900 i am using 32 bit OS 2gb ram. i dont know how to use gc() can you help me out with the code

Comment: Type `gc()` into the terminal, and show what output you get.  Then try running `pred<-predict(c,traindata)` after that and see what happens.

Comment: @mrip its not working again the same error is showing. do you have any other alternatives

Comment: What is the output when you run `gc()`?  That will tell you how much memory you are using.  This will help you determine whether you are using too much memory or if it is something else.

Comment: @mrip this what showing. can you explain it? 
 > gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells   427259  11.5     741108  19.8   741108  19.8
Vcells 37343512 285.0   78022355 595.3 78021061 595.3
> pred<-predict(c,traindata)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 98.7 Mb

Comment: That doesn't seem like you are using too much memory.  Are you running R on windows?  If so, you might have a memory limit.  Try `memory.limit()` to see and then try something like `memory.limit(1000)`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, here are a few things to try if you are having memory issues in R:

1) Garbage collect.  Running `gc()` will run the garbage collector, and it will also tell you how much memory you are currenty using:

```
> a<-double(1e6)
> b<-double(1e9)
> gc()
             used   (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)   max used   (Mb)
Ncells     182079    9.8     407500   21.8     350000   18.7
Vcells 1001277242 7639.2 1104245379 8424.8 1001438032 7640.4
```

2) Get rid of big objects.  You can get a list of the 10 biggest objects by size in megs using this command:

```
> sort(sapply(ls(),function(x) object.size(get(x))),T)[1:10]/1e6
         b          a       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 
8000.00004    8.00004         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA 
      <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 
        NA         NA         NA
```

In this case, I just have two objects, since this is a fresh R session.  But this allows me to spot the culprit and get rid of it if I don't need it anymore using `rm`:

```
> rm(b)
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)   max used   (Mb)
Ncells  183576  9.9     407500   21.8     350000   18.7
Vcells 1280024  9.8  883396303 6739.8 1001773436 7643.0
```

3) If, after clearing out big objects and garbage collecting, you still have memory issues, then you might want to look into an R package that allows you to deal with large datasets using memory mapped files.  Some options are `mmap` and `bigmemory`.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mmap/index.html

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html

Comment: as you have taken a and b what should i take in my case can you suggest me or should i use this two object only a and b

Comment: > a<-double(1e6)
> 
> b<-double(1e9)
Error in double(1e+09) : cannot allocate vector of length 1000000000
> 
> b<-double(1e8)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 762.9 Mb
> 
> b<-double(1e7)
> 
> sort(sapply(ls(),function(x) object.size(get(x))),T)[1:10]/1e6
 traindata          b   testdata          a          c    weights      index         f1 
103.944888  80.000024  44.831592   8.000024   0.083684   0.044352   0.022312   0.021792 
    tindex  class_col 
  0.015624   0.000032  this is what showing what shoul i do here please help

Comment: You shouldn't actually run that code, it's just an example to illustrate how to find and get rid of big objects that you might have allocated and forgotten about.

Comment: why did you remove b and not a

Comment: then how will i get rid of big object which are of no use to me

Comment: I don't know which objects are of no use to you.  Only you can know that.  Are you running windows?  Have you tried memory.limit(1000)?

Comment: i am running windows XP. no how does memory.limit(1000) works i didnt try it. what made you convince to remove b.

Comment: Run `memory.limit(1000)` and then try `predict` again.  If that doesn't work try `memory.limit(1500)`.  If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.  I chose b arbitrarily, just to illustrate how to remove objects.  You have to figure out for yourself if there are any objects you have hanging around that you don't need anymore.

Comment: is this because of low ram memory

Comment: > memory.limit(1500)
[1] 2047
Warning message:
In memory.size(size) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
> pred<-predict(c,traindata)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 98.7 Mb this is what showing

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm stumped.  It looks like you are running out of memory, but it also looks like you have plenty of memory left.  Maybe look at what the `naiveBayes.predict` function is doing.  I wouldn't think it would require that much memory.

Comment: how could i do that as you suggest naiveBayes.predict actualy naivebayes is predicting the test data and as test data is huge it cannot allocate the required memory..